# Why do I have "Checksum fail" on every bad SQL request in Oracle when Native Encryption (ASO) is enabled?

Tags: java, oracle, encryption, jdbc, java-7

We recently configured our Oracle database to be in so-called `native encryption` (Oracle Advanced Security Option).

As development goes on, some `SQL` queries are sometimes badly-written and so an error should be returned by the `JDBC` driver (`ojdbc7 v12.1.0.2`). Instead of that, a `Checksum Fail IOException` is raised.

So the problem is that we do not have anymore any syntax or database integrity error at all. The problem is the same in SQL GUI editors, like `DBeaver`, `SQLDeveloper` or `SQuirrel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue in the Oracle JDBC thin driver. If you can use SSL instead of ASO then this problem will go away.

Comment: The bug is 20960881 and is fixed in the 12.2.0.1 version of the driver.

Comment: We are experiencing similar error on a SAP Java 6 system. Is this bug also known for ojdbc6 driver and is there fix for JRE 6 runtime?

Answer (score 9):

With driver ojdbc7 12.1.0.1 the correct VM parameter names are as follows:

```
-Doracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=REQUIRED
-Doracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=SHA1
```

Answer (score 6):

Driver version 12.1 and earlier have a bug in SHA-2 functions
If able force the server to handshake with SHA-1

```
-Doracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=REQUIRED
-Doracle.net.crypto_checksum_types=SHA1
```

This is fixed in ojdbc8.jar version 12.2

Answer (score 2):

Our team is also experiencing the same issue.

Determined that setting the WebLogic Connection Pool to use either SHA1 or MD5 for Checksum Encryption resolved the issue (also had to add the chosen value to the list of approved algorithms in the DB-server's sqlnet.ora file of course).

Attempts to use any Checksum value on the client side aside from SHA1 or MD5 produced the Checksum Fail error message when Oracle attempted to return a 'standard' error ie Constraint Violation.

Comment: Ah thank you. I will test this. I think we use SHA256 and our security policy prevent us from using SHA1 or MD5 but I want to test this nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

**if you are inserting record to data base and see the error then

1. check your insert values and schema, you might be inserting null
   value in FK reference
2. you might be inserting null in not null column

**

Oracle wont give the correct information for this error