# Oracle exception

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

In my java application when I read a record from Oracle database I have this Exception :

```
SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006

Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Errore di I/O: Checksum fail
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:792)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor241.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy256.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
... 197 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Checksum fail
at oracle.net.ano.CryptoDataPacket.receive(Unknown Source)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:305)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89)
at
```

Could you help me?

Comment: can you provide code how you read data from database?

Comment: Which version of the driver are you using?  "java -jar ojdbc7.jar" will tell you.

Comment: Maybe this? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323204/why-do-i-have-checksum-fail-on-every-bad-sql-request-in-oracle-when-native-enc

Answer (score 0):

The text tells us `Errore di I/O` ;

- The exception may relate to configuration (e.g. timeout period) of
  the Oracle database server
- The exception may be due to error conditions in the database server
- The exception may be due to a defect in the database server or driver

  First of all, try to use `tnsping` for database alias in your `TNS` file :

  ```
  C:\Users\pc>tnsping <dbAlias>
  ```

  If command returns without success, then you need to configure the `TNS` file, else look at the status of your listener for your db :

  ```
  C:\Users\pc>lsnrctl status
  ```

if your listener is up. If not, start :

```
    C:\Users\pc>lsnrctl start
```